# Run CMD command in android app programmatically

Tags: android

Can I run cmd command in Android programmatically that will run an exe file's command to update a firmware file in a BLE device? and can i place that exe file in my assets folder or it should be outside of application in local storage of device?

Comment: `EXE` is a Windows file format. Android is not Windows. Android cannot run Windows `EXE` files.

Comment: @CommonsWare , Thanks. Is there any way using which i can update firmware file on BLE device from android app?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the BLE device.